# Sync Linux system with Windows over SSH while retaining file permissions

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, sync, file-permissions

I am trying to sync files between my Linux machine and my Windows machine over SSH (SFTP). Currently when I do this, the files lose their Unix file permissions because windows doesn't support Unix permissions.

Is there some way that I could store the file permissions in separate file on my Windows machine when I sync from the Linux PC, and then restore those permissions when I sync the files back to my Linux machine?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!